# Identifying a connected plate on a gear liquid-metering pump

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, pumps

This is part of an electric resin-extruding machine.

What's the part, and if possible, who makes it?

Any additional information regarding what the part is, or what the assembly is called, is greatly appreciated.

Here's the part:

[image: Connected plate]

Here's the back side:

[image: Plate back side]

Here's where it connects:

[image: Connect to assembly]

[image: Connected example]

Comment: We migrated this question because we thought some mechanical engineers or machinists could help this guy out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After extensive searching, it appears the part is referred to as a "driving flange" by the manufacturer's technical diagram, which I've included below.

Additionally, the pump itself seems to be an SPT gear metering pump made by Slack & Parr.

[image: Technical Diagram]
[image: Technical CAD Drawing]

Comment: Good find, I do still wonder about the purpose as if all it does is drive then it would only need the slot matching the male protrusion - why go to the extra expense of machining the extended slots?

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that it may be a torque limiter - similar to shear bolts.

Does the gear with the two slotted cheese or pan head screws freely rotate on its shaft ? Then with the plate fitted it is then locked? If so, then those "teeth" are designed to break first before something else if a blockage etc happens.

Comment: I don't know enough to confirm this either; but it seems like an extremely reasonable explanation.

Comment: @JMac thanks - I could not see any other purpose really.

Comment: While this does help me understand the function of the part, I'm still lacking enough information to be able to locate a replacement, which is the end-goal of identifying this. Do you have any additional info on possibly what type of torque limiter this might be called, or anything else that might help?

Comment: Try a Shear plate...